# continuos function f(x,y) in (0,0) without iterated limit

Tags: limits

Does anyone know some example of a function, which is continuous in (0,0) but its iterated limit doesn´t exist? I mean for example one limit absolutely doesn´t exist, not that they are different.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}x\sin\frac1y=0\;,\;\;\text{but}\;\;\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\lim_{y\to 0}x\sin\frac1y\right)\;\;\;\text{doesn't exist}$$